# Enable Arabic Support in RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, language

I'm trying to enable Arabic support on VM. I set the locale to ar_SA.utf8. What I want is to type Arabic characters in Gedit to test. After setting locale, I log off, and when I tried to login it shows gibberish as shown in image

[image]

I also change the language to French and it's working well

[image]

And localectl status

```
> [root@mserver (~)]# >  localectl status    System Locale:
> LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
>        VC Keymap: us-acentos
>       X11 Layout: us
>        X11 Model: pc105
>      X11 Variant: intl
```

And Yum Langlist output shows Arabic Language is install already

```
[root@mserver (~)]# >  yum langlist
Modules complémentaires chargés : aliases, changelog, langpacks, ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Installed languages:
        Arabic
```

Comment: My best guess would be that you also need some fonts to match.

Answer (score 1):

[RedHat officially supports 22 languages on RHEL7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/7.0_release_notes/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-7.0_release_notes-internationalization), Arabic is not one of the officially supported languages though. If Arabic locale is installed, you should still be able to see the characters rendered (maybe not in the menus or various other window panels) so long as you have some Arabic fonts installed, e.g., fonts-hosny-amiri.

You should be able to search for Arabic fonts with Yum:

For example: `yum search amiri` or `yum search naskh`

Note: Apologies for not noticing the comments section, @schaiba 's comment would have constituted an answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In installation and setup you may install languages, use also

```
yum search lang*
```

or

```
yum install *Arab* -y
```

I think this will install all Arabic language support.

Linux Basic Commands:

- https://youtu.be/DV-73rmGJy0
- https://youtu.be/UUxCWQD0mB8
- https://youtu.be/KkgCalbm-og
- https://youtu.be/0RugMejaTjY
- https://youtu.be/8eThovfya6k
- https://youtu.be/mCsJKGSlToA